# C++: free or destroy malloc'd char * after it is captured by a local string?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c-strings

Suppose I do the following:

```
char *get_data(...) {
    char *c_style = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    load_c_string_with_my_c_function(c_style, length, input);
    return c_style;
}

int main() {
   std::string data(get_data(...));
   // free(data.c_str()); ?? -- are the malloc'd bytes now managed?
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to release the memory that `get_data()` allocated?  Would the commented `free(data.c_str());` Work?

Comment: You have a memory leak, the pointer returned by `get_data` is lost forever. The `std::string` object manages its *own* data and memory.

Comment: Also, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). The question should be in the actual question body, while keeping the title a short summary of your problem.

Comment: Why `malloc` to begin with? That's the problem.

Comment: it's better to return `std::string` so you'll have its copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you do

```
std::string data(get_data(...));
```

there is no way to get the pointer back that `get_data()` returned so you will leak that memory.  To fix this just have `get_data()` return a `std::string` in the first place so you don't have to worry about memory management at all.  That would give you

```
std::string get_data(...) {
    std::string data(length, '\0');
    load_c_string_with_my_c_function(data.data(), length, input); // requires C++17
    // load_c_string_with_my_c_function(&data[0], length, input); // use this for pre-C++17 compilers
    return data;
}
```

and now no memory leak.  If you can't do this then you need to capture the pointer, use it to initialize the string, and then free the pointer like

```
char* ret = get_data(...);
std::string data(ret);
free(ret);
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Coming out of C and back into C++. Will accept when the timer runs out.

Comment: @bordeo I get it.  They behave pretty differently so it can be difficult to get back into the C++ way of doing things (RAII FTW)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call call `free(data.c_str());` or anything like that. `std::string` manages its own memory and even the pointer that you get from `c_str()` is invalidated automatically as soon as the `std::string` goes out of scope.

You do, however, need to free the `c_style` returned from the function call. The `std::string` may handle its own memory, but it is only a copy of the `malloc`'d memory that isn't managed.

Do this:

```
int main() {
    char *result = (get_data(...)
    std::string data(result);
    // free(data.c_str()); ?? -- are the malloc'd bytes now managed?
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so ideally I copy nothing. It seems like the thrust of this question is capturing the bytes of the malloc with the string.

Comment: "capturing" = copying by value each characters until string terminator.

Comment: By making an `std::string` with the returned `char*` you are already copying it.

Comment: @KamilCuk "capturing" = directly managing the memory, so moving ownership of the bytes, rather than passing by reference or copy. Not language specific.

Comment: @KamilCuk if you use "capture" for some other meaning, then it overlaps with copy, and, in more general context, it becomes impossible to describe the case of malloc'ing data in calling code, and passing the pointer to a struct whose destructor is responsible for disposing of the data.

Comment: `s/You don't need to/You can't/`

Comment: Right! Thanks for the tip, added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to release the memory that `get_data()` allocated?

No, you lost your pointer to it.

> Would the commented `free(data.c_str());` Work?

No. The `std::string` copied your data into a new string that it owns and manages. You cannot legally de-allocate the `std::string`'s own allocated memory, and it would not solve the problem of having to de-allocate your original allocated memory.

Either use `std::string` throughout (preferred!) or capture the pointer inside `main` first:

```
int main()
{
   auto cstr = get_data(...);
   std::string data(cstr);
   free(cstr);
}
```

Trouble is, this isn't exception-safe, which is why we have nice things like `std::string` in the first place. It can be solved with some liberal `try` and `catch` but it'll be ugly.

Also, since you already have `get_data`, presumably for a reason, you might consider a `string_view` over the actual memory that you already allocated, unless you really need `data` to be an owning copy.

```
int main()
{
   auto cstr = get_data(...);
   std::string_view data(cstr);  // no copy! just features
   free(cstr);
}
```

*(Comments elsewhere indicate that this may be what you really wanted.)*

Now experiment with having `get_data` return something with clear ownership & lifetime semantics (`std::unique_ptr`? `std::vector`? `std::string`? .. lol) and you're golden.

Comment: The only thing I dislike about using a `std::string_view` here is you have to defer the call to `free(cstr)` until you are done with the `std::string_view`.  Could make it easier to forget to do, once again causing a leak.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Indeed

Comment: `get_data` doesn't fail with an exception, it just returns the `nullptr` from `malloc`. So the code as written has Undefined Behavior when you pass that `nullptr` to `std::string`. Exception Safety would become an issue only if you manually translate that `nullptr` into `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: @MSalters `std::string` construction can throw. If it does, you've lost `*cstr`.

Comment: @MSalters Good point about the `nullptr` though - that needs some care before we construct a `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the pointer, you aren't keeping a reference to it. You need to do:

```
int main() {
   char* cstr = get_data(...);
   std::string data(cstr);
   free(cstr);
   return 0;
}
```

Or much better write your data into the string directly:

```
std::string get_data(...) {
    std::string data(length, '\0');
    load_c_string_with_my_c_function(&data[0], data.size(), input);
    return data;
}
```

You may need to add 1 to the length of the `std::string` and/or pass `data.size()-1` to `load_c_string_with_my_c_function` depending on the specification of the `length` parameter of `load_c_string_with_my_c_function`.